# updating template with response in Ember after create/update action

Tags: ember.js

I am working on a simple CRUD app using ember js. I have a template with a input form which sends data to the server and server responds with success response.

input form data:     "user": {"id": 1, "name": "John"};
server response:     {"message":"Created successfully", "nextId": 2}.

I want to display the success message on the same template(one with the input form). Because template refers to the user model and user model does not have a message attribute. How can it be done? Please help.

Here is my code:

```
var Manager = Ember.Application.create();

Manager.Router.map(function() {
   this.resource('users');
   this.resource('user', {path: '/users/:user_id'});
   this.resource('home', {path: '/'});
});


Manager.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
       return jQuery.getJSON("http://localhost:8085/users/"+ params.user_id);
   },

   actions :{
       insert : function(){
           var user = this.modelFor("User");
           $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8085/Users", 
                data: JSON.stringify(user),
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
           })
           .done(function(data){
            //set data.message to display on UI 
           })
       }
   }
});
```

and my template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" {{action "insert" on="submit"}}>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userId" class="control-label col-xs-2">User Id</label>
            <div class="col-xs-4 input-group">
                {{input type="number" value=_id class="form-control" id="userId" placeholder="Identity"}}
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-2">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-4 input-group">
                {{input type="text" value=name class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name"}}
            </div>
    </div>

    {{#if message}}
        <div class="alert alert-success input-group" role="alert">{{message}}</div>
    {{/if}} 

    <div class="form-group button-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? Templates, Controllers, etc?

Comment: @Oren, I have added my template and js.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `message` property on your controller to the response that comes back.

```
actions :{
       insert : function(){
           var user = this.modelFor("User");
           var self = this;
           $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8085/Users", 
                data: JSON.stringify(user),
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
           })
           .done(function(data){
               //set data.message to display on UI 
               self.controllerFor('user').set('message', data.message);
           })
       }
   }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried this, but this adds an attribute 'message' in the user model, which is what I don't want.

Comment: @jcena - This is setting the message property on the User Controller, not the User Model. Your template is bound to the property on the controller. The way ember works now is that is that the controller will proxy the property on the model if the controller doesn't contain a property with the same name. Is the behavior as expected when you use the implementation I posted?